# How to set time zone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I'm working in rails and I am trying to figure out how to set the time zone so `Time.now` gives me

```
Mon, 03 Jun 2019 19:08:13 CDT -05:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# application.rb

class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end

Time.zone      # => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x514834...>
Time.zone.name # => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.now  # => Sun, 18 May 2008 14:30:44 EDT -04:00
```

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: That gives me a string does it not?  I need class Time

Comment: @Blue the time itself does not have a display format.

Also, this answer will always say that it is in CDT, even when it is not.

Comment: `Time` is not a format, it's a class that encapsulates a value. If you want it formatted you want a string.

Comment: Thank you, the update was exactly what I looking for.

Comment: @iCodeSometime The edit was exactly what I was looking for, I don't know if you consider that a format but incase you run into someone asking a question similar to mine there are multiple ways to display Time